# Partial derivative puzzle, the solution is (probably) either easy or doesn't exist but my calculus is too weak, please help!

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

$f$ and $\phi$ are functions of $P$ and related as follows:

$$\phi(P) = \frac{f(P)}{P}$$

I am currently able to calculate the quantity: $$\frac{\partial ln(\phi(P))}{\partial P} = constant$$

using a black-box calculator I have available to me for some value of P.

I would like to calculate the value of:

$$\frac{\partial f(P)}{\partial P}$$

for some value of P.

Is this possible? It's been many years since Calculus class for me.

Comment: Just write $f(P) = P \phi(P)$ and differentiate using the product rule to get $P \phi '(P)+\phi (P)$

Comment: @flinty Please post your comment as an answer -- comments aren't for answering questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

$$
f(P) = P\phi(P)
$$

Differentiate with the product rule to get:
$$
f'(p)=P\phi'(P)+\phi(P)
$$

...and use the chain rule and that the derivative of $\ln(x)$ is $1/x$:
$$\frac{\partial \ln(\phi(P))}{\partial P} = \frac{\phi '(P)}{\phi(P)} = \text{constant}$$
... then you have:
$$f'(P) = (P \cdot  \text{constant} + 1) \phi(P)$$

Comment: This seems like exactly what I'm looking for, but before I accept it as an answer can you please explain how you came up with the third equation (∂ln(ϕ(P))∂P=ϕ′(P)ϕ(P)=constant)?

Comment: @Pierre use the chain rule which says derivative of $F(G(x))$ is $\frac{d F}{d G} \frac{d G}{d x}$. Let $F = \ln$ and $G = \phi$ We have $\frac{d \ln(\phi)}{d\phi} = \frac{1}{\phi}$ so $\frac{d \ln(\phi(x))}{d x} = \frac{1}{\phi} \cdot \frac{d \phi}{d x}$

Comment: Thank you! It makes perfect sense now. This is hugely helpful to me.